# Parallel algorithm benchmarking tools for testing on multicore x86 CPUs

Tags: algorithm, x86, parallel-processing, benchmarking, multicore

We want to build a parallel algorithm benchmarking lab for multicore x86 CPUs and we want to know if there are any suggestions on how to do it. We want it to give us messurements as deterministic as possible, so we have been researching several possibilities:

- **OS**

  - RT Linux
  - BareMetal OS (http://www.returninfinity.com/baremetal.html)
- **Programming Language**

  - Low Level: Assembler or C (These are the only 2 possibilities if BareMetal is used)
  - High Level: RT Python or RT Java

We think the most deterministic option would be BareMetal OS with Assembler, but if we can use higher level languages without big degradations in the results, we would prefer it. Any suggestions about how to get the best results while preserving programming productivity?

Thanks

Comment: You can only use Python if you use multiprocessing (Python can't run multiple threads simultaneously), which limits the selection of algorithms you can test with it.

Comment: We actually don't want to use threads but distribute the work between cores. Nevertheless, I thought python supported multiple threads based on this: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading

Comment: Python supports multiple threads; they just can't run on multiple cores at the same time. If you want to use threads to distribute the work between cores, Python will not work. If you don't need to test shared-memory algorithms, Python can be used with multiple processes.

Comment: Since I want to distribute work between cores, then I will need to use http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing. Then I will also be able to test shared-memory algorithms, right?

Comment: You will be able to use shared memory, but your selection of data structures will be severely limited. Anything beyond simple arrays will require the use of managers which can limit the scalability of your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe. That makes python limitations in this regard a lot more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I did a lot of this parallel program benchmarking for my thesis. Built a large suite of parallel workloads and ran it on real x86 machines for performance measurements. I get a feeling that you are choosing a language to teach parallel programming -- if that is the case I would just go with C and assembly. Assembly is a bit too low level for many items but it is the write answer to explain synchronization primitives. I wrote my own thread primitives in assembly and it was a rewarding experience.

I may be wrong but I think @Gabe is right about python threads running on the same core.

I disagree with @powerrox that MPI is a good idea. I however love open MP. I always had my students start with pthreads, then move to OpenMP. pthreads provides understanding of whats going on under the hood and then OpenMP provides elegant and clean coding without having to deal with pthread (void **)(void *).

Answer (score 1):

The most popular way to have the most productive parallel processing across multiple systems is MPI.

If you are talking only about multi core, multi CPU single system using shared memory, aim for OpenMP and pThreads. Fair warning, badly written OpenMP or pThreads does not scale. pThread programing can be very complicated.

OpenMP is well suited for domain decomposition problems. pThreads is the only option for task decomposition. OpenMP new spec might support task decomposition.

And if you want to use assembler to achieve parallel programing - good luck to you. cant be done in a productive way.

And Gabe, python does support multiple-threads. And threads can run on multiple cores and does not limit the selection of data structures in anyway. You CAN use python with threads to distribute work among multiple threads that run on multiple cores.

I would be very cautious to go with gabe's comments. In my opinion, his comments are very misleading.